# Can BOT present in ASE environment can be deployed in MS Team app?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework, microsoft-teams

I was able to successfully use the web channel, using app service extension token outside the ASE environment through internet facing messaging endpoint but in msteams app , we are get using Microsoft ID to create MS app package !
Context - BOT is kept in IL ASE environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got confirmation from MS like - "Azure ASE is currently not supported by Teams Bot Service".
so it is not possible for adding or using MS Team channel from the BOT that is present in ASE environment.

Also if we make the BOT messaging endpoint public facing, then we can use it. I was able to get response once i whitelisted the endpoint and after proper routing in azure.